# .htaccess not working properly, changing profile page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am currently having problem using htaccess and i want use profile.php?u=rahulkapoor as www.domain.com/rahulkapoor where u is for username. but it is not working properly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and here is profile.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
    //check user exists
    $check = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, first_name FROM users2 WHERE username='$username'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check)===1) {
    $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
    $username = $get['username'];
    $firstname = $get['first_name'];    
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=/index.php\">"; 
    exit();
    }
    }
}
 $get_info = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name,email FROM users2 WHERE username='$username'");
  $get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_info);
  $name = $get_row['name'];
  $email = $get_row['email'];
?>
```

when some enters wrong username,it should redirect to index page but instead it is showing the page as it is for any parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/?$ /profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Be sure to change the target url `www.example.com`to your domain name.

Comment: @Rahulkapoor it is working fine for me, I just tested it on my apache server, I entered a url in this format => http://example.com/me and it was internally redirected to www.example.com/profile.php?u=me

Comment: yes it is working, but when i use any username that is not in database it is not redirecting to the index page, see profile.php for this.

Comment: @Rahulkapoor when you enter a username that is not in the database you can simply redirect these requests using php Header location function in your profile.php page, it can not be redirected by .htaccess, php is a very easy solution for this.

Comment: i am redirecting in profile.php only, can you see meta tag in else part.

Comment: anything here for me?